# Create a table with elements in column

Tags: html, angular

I have to create a table whith elements like:

| Header1 | Header2 | Header2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Data1 | Data2 | Data3 |

I have headers and data taken from api call.

I have tried something like:

```
<table class="table">
    <div *ngFor="let element of apiResp">
        <tr>
            <th>{{element.header}}</th>
            <td>{{element.data}}</td>
        </tr>
    </div>
</table>
```

but the result is:

> Header1 Data1
>
> Header2 Data2
>
> Header3 Data3

Comment: `<tr>` is **t**able **r**ow, so you will get rows by using that element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `<div>` are not displayed horizontally but vertically.

What you are trying to do is probably:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
       <th *ngFor="let element of apiResp">{{element.header}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td *ngFor="let element of apiResp">{{element.data}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<tr>
   <th>{{element.header}}</th>
</tr>
<tr>
   <th>{{element.data}}</th>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid additional tags inside the table. The table wouldn't work as expected if there would be other tags then the table tags (such as tr for TableRow, th for TableHead cell and td for TableData cell etc.)

Comment: You would consider providing a sample in answer. That would help people to understand your answer better.